# Creating a Google calendar event on specific days using IFTTT

Tags: google-calendar, if-this-then-that

I'm using [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) to manage my smart home. When the sun sets ([Weather Underground](https://ifttt.com/weather)) then a Google calendar event is created. I need that the event will be created only on the upcoming Friday. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible in the "easy" way of connecting an applet from a trigger and an action, but I'm pretty sure you can do it in the [maker](https://platform.ifttt.com/maker/) area

Comment: Thanks. I've done it with the apilio.io service by creating a logicbox and variables.

Answer (score -3):

I've done it with the apilio.io service by creating a logicbox and variables

Comment: Please read about [How do I write a good answer?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)